# How to reload hidden jqGrid from jquery - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

While using  helper classes from Lib.Web.Mvc 3. i ran into an issue .

Issue-

I’m setting  set the hidden property of jqGrid to true so that on the first page load it is not visible. But when user selects an item  from  list the hidden property is set to false for the grid and reload trigger is initiated  . But for some reason controller actions are never getting called after an item is selected and reload rigger occurs. I’m newbie to MVC so please pardon me for silly question if it is.Thank you!.

```
<div id="gridWrapper">
@{

var grid = new JqGridHelper<Configuration.Models.Post.ProfileModel>(
    "Servers",
    caption: "Servers List",
    hidden: true,
    hiddenEnabled: true,
    dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
    methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
    pager: true,
    rowsNumber: 10,
    sortingName: "Profile",
    sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
    url: Url.Action("GetServersWithSettings"),
    editingUrl: Url.Action("Edit"),
    loadComplete: "function (data) {var recs =    
    parseInt($(\"#Servers\").getGridParam(\"records\"),10);" +
                  "if (isNaN(recs) || recs == 0) {" +
                  "$(\"#gridWrapper\").hide();" +
                  "}" +
                  "else {$('#gridWrapper').show();" +
                  "}"+"}",

    sortable: true
  ).Navigator(new JqGridNavigatorOptions
    {
        Add = true,
        Delete = false,
        //Edit = true,
        View = false
    })
    .FilterToolbar(new JqGridFilterToolbarOptions
    {
        StringResult = true,
        DefaultSearchOperator = JqGridSearchOperators.Cn,
        AutoSearch = true,
        SearchOnEnter = false,

    });
    @grid.GetHtml()
}
</div>



@section scripts {

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet"   
 type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-
ui.css" />
<style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected {background: #F39814;color: white; }
    #selectable {list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 60%; }
    #selectable li {margin: 3px;padding: 0.4em;font-size: 1.4em;height: 18px; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @grid.GetJavaScript();
       })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            // callback function to bring a hidden box back
    $(function() {
        $("#selectable").selectable({
            stop: function() {
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                    var url = 'Profile/GetServersWithSettings/?id=' +                                             
                               $(this).attr('id');
                    $("#Servers").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: url 
                    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
              });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: I recommend you write loadCompete: "myCompletefunction" and then define your function in Javascript block. You are doing it correct just check in Firebug or Chrome Dev tools what network calls are going out to GetServerwithSettings and it is not giving anyother errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change it from hidden: true to: $(this).Hide()

Then at the function write $(this).Show()

Comment: $(this).Hide()...where do i put this above within document.ready function?.. @Eyal Elmakies